# ubuntu is trying to upgade from 14.04 to 12.10

Tags: 14.04, 12.10, upgrade

I'm currently on **14.04** and I want to upgrade to **14.10**. When I changed the updates status from *only LTS* to *any version* I was asked to upgrade to **12.10**. But I want to upgrade to **14.10**, is there a way to fix this?

Note this is note a typo it actually says **12.10**.

EDIT: not sure how to attach screenshots, so here they are in an Imgur album https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcLyG.jpg

Lsb_release -a:

```
No LSB modules are available.  
Distributor ID: Ubuntu  
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS  
Release:    12.04  
Codename:   precise
```

apt-cache policy update-manager-core:

```
update-manager-core:  
  Installed: 1:0.156.14.17  
  Candidate: 1:0.156.14.17  
   Version table:  
 *** 1:0.156.14.17 0  
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main i386 Packages  
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status  
     1:0.156.14.5 0  
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main i386 Packages  
     1:0.156.14 0  
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages
```

as far as I know I should be running 14.04... but for some reason all of these say I'm running 12.04.5

I am really confused at this point.

Comment: William: Are you sure that it said 12.10?  12.10 isn't even available in the repositories and hasn't been for some time, so it makes no sense that your system would say 12.10.  Are you sure it didn't say 14.10?

Comment: I just followed your steps and changed 'only lts' to 'any version'.  The prompt shows 14.10, not 12.10.  Please confirm that it actually said 12.10 instead of 14.10.  (An Lubuntu VM and an Xubuntu VM also show the same - 14.10, not 12.10)

Comment: just to confirm, I did not make a typo. I am currently running fourteen point four, and when I change my update manager to "for any new version" it offers to upgrade me to twelve point ten.

Comment: Did this installation start out as 14.04 or is it 12.04 upgraded to 14.04? I could imagine a situation where some file still has 12.04 written all over it and confused the update manager.

Comment: @WilliamGates Please include a screenshot (or copy/paste from terminal if commandline) of what you're seeing on your screen by [edit]ing your question. Please also show the results of running `lsb_release -a` and `apt-cache policy update-manager-core`.

Comment: I cleaned up the question and I hope it became clearer to everyone, can you please add a screenshot of the message? (go to update manager and select lts only and then any version again and you should recive it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're *not* running 14.04 as you indicated, but you're actually running 12.04. All the output you show support this scenario.

Therefore, the proposed upgrade to 12.10 is valid. However, I recommend *not* to run this. Once on 12.10 you'll have to go through the long process of 12.10 → 13.04 → 13.10 → 14.04 to reach a supported release. LTS → LTS+1 upgrade path is supported and is a lot quicker. So instead, just [upgrade to 14.04 directly from 12.04](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseNotes#Upgrading_from_Ubuntu_12.04_LTS_or_Ubuntu_13.10).